# How to display PDF on the HTML page

Tags: java, spring, wicket, wicket-8

I have migrated my application from wicket 1.x to wicket 8.x and now facing an error to display PDF on iframe. It is showing as blank on the iframe.

I am trying to display PDF in the iframe tag in the HTML on page load but it is showing as blank.

Share the detailed code below path:
https://github.com/smartuadk/Shared_Repo_StackOverflow/tree/main/PDF_Preview

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs or JavaScript errors in the browser ? Show us your code.

Comment: Where is the iframe ?

Comment: Iframe is loading on this Id "resourcePanel" in TestPDFPreview.html page. Its defined under this method  onComponentTag() in TestResourcePanel.java. Kindly check I have committed 2 new files.

Comment: Not sure why simple iframe tag <iframe src="c:\\test.pdf"></iframe> also not displaying PDF in the wicket html page. But able to see PDF in iframe in the normal html page.

Comment: Hi @martin-g, please find the GitHub repository path for the code details - 
https://github.com/smartuadk/Shared_Repo_StackOverflow/tree/main/PDF_Preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below http security header tag in Spring security module xml file to allow Spring security to display the HTML iframe in spring application:

```
<security:http use-expressions="false">
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options disabled="true"></security:frame-options>
    </security:headers>
</security:http>
```

This solution worked for me and now my application is able to display the iFrame without any error and able to load PDF file in iFrame as well.